# Is it possible to avoid the names repeating in command line?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, powershell, cmd

I learn Webpack [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/). I didn't know about `&&`. My question is about the command:

```
mkdir webpack-demo && cd webpack-demo
```

the webpack-demo was mentioned twice here. Is it possible to avoid such repeating for avoid of misprint? I.e. something like

```
mkdir webpack-demo && cd $0
```

Comment: In PowerShell you could do `mkdir webpack-demo |%{cd $_}` (or `mkdir webpack-demo |cd` if you don't care about the prompt message)

Comment: With the alias md it's even shorter `md webpack-demo|cd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `&&` tells in any command(s) to make sure all the commands mentioned in terminal should be successful(they will be separated by pipe), if any of the command fails then both(or how many or present) of them will not run. So following ways could help you(Though your whole objective is not there so only keeping your question into my mind as of now).

**1st way:** By creating a script with an argument.

```
cat script.ksh
value=$1
mkdir $value
cd $value
```

Run the script now(Obviously by providing the correct permissions).

```
./script.ksh test_directory
```

**2nd way:** Do a one-liner where you have to give value of directory 1 time and it will run the command(you need not to type two times).

```
value=dir_name;mkdir $value && cd $value
```

**3rd way:** By which you need to run command from terminal and it should create directory and should navigate inside in it too.

```
mkdir dir_name && cd $_
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

    `rm -rf webpack-demo
    cd $(mkdir -v webpack-demo| awk '{ print $NF }' | tr -d \' )`

But not I think the original was simple enough...

Answer (score 0):

in PowerShell

Solution 1 (with alias and pass result to pipe):

```
mkdir "c:\temp\tmp8" | cd
```

Solution 2 (without alias) :

```
New-Item  "c:\temp\tmp6" -ItemType Directory | Set-Location
```

Solution 3 (with semi-coma and last command)

```
mkdir "c:\temp\tmp9"  ; cd $$
```